# Why does performance of java stream fall off with relatively large work compared to "for" loop?

Tags: java, java-stream, benchmarking, jmh

I had an earlier question about interpreting JMH output, which was mostly answered, but I updated the question with another related question, but it would be better to have this be a separate question.

This is the original question: [Verify JMH measurements of simple for/lambda comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349631/verify-jmh-measurements-of-simple-for-lambda-comparisons) .

My question has to do with performance of streams at particular levels of "work".  The following excerpted results from the previous question illustrates what I'm wondering about:

```
Benchmark                                            Mode  Cnt          Score         Error  Units
MyBenchmark.shortLengthConstantSizeFor              thrpt  200  132278188.475 ± 1132184.820  ops/s
MyBenchmark.shortLengthConstantSizeLambda           thrpt  200   18750818.019 ±  171239.562  ops/s
MyBenchmark.mediumLengthConstantSizeFor             thrpt  200   55447999.297 ±  277442.812  ops/s
MyBenchmark.mediumLengthConstantSizeLambda          thrpt  200   15925281.039 ±   65707.093  ops/s
MyBenchmark.longerLengthConstantSizeFor             thrpt  200    3551842.518 ±   42612.744  ops/s
MyBenchmark.longerLengthConstantSizeLambda          thrpt  200    2791292.093 ±   12207.302  ops/s
MyBenchmark.longLengthConstantSizeFor               thrpt  200       2984.554 ±      57.557  ops/s
MyBenchmark.longLengthConstantSizeLambda            thrpt  200        331.741 ±       2.196  ops/s
```

I was expecting, as the tests moved from shorter lists to longer lists, that the performance of the stream test should approach the performance of the "for" test.

I saw that in the "short" list, the stream performance was 14% of the "for" performance.  For the medium list, it was 29%.  For the longer list, it was 78%. So far, the trend was what I was expecting.  However, for the long list, it is 11%.  For some reason, a list size of 300k, as opposed to 300, caused the performance of the stream to drop off, compared to the "for".

I was wondering if anyone could corroborate results like this, and whether they had any thoughts about why it might be happening.

I'm running this on a Win7 laptop with Java 8.

Comment: Related queston: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687717/java-8-stream-unpredictable-performance-drop-with-no-obvious-reason

Comment: @DanielWiddis fascinating read, thanks for posting

Answer (score 1):

Well, streams are quite a new addition to Java compared to the "for loop", and the JIT Compiler does not do any sophisticated optimizations for them, yet, as it does for the loops over arrays or collections.